# Deploying a Django app on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, pythonanywhere

I am new at Django and I have made an app.  Here is the link to the github repository: https://github.com/akashmalla07/spring.  I followed this http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/ to deploy my code, and while running `python manage.py migrate` i am getting this error

```
ImportError: No module named 'django_nose'
```

I did not get this problem while developing on my local machine, but I am getting this problem on PythonAnywhere.  Please help me.  Thanks in advance

edited 
   after following your solution i got this error

```
  File "/tmp/pip-build-_l_qs3mn/wsgiref/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ez_setup
  File "/tmp/pip-build-_l_qs3mn/wsgiref/ez_setup/__init__.py", line 170
    print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
                             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-
 build-_l_qs3mn/wsgiref/
```

And i have referred to other stackoverflow solution i.e

```
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

but didnot worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your project requires a number of extra modules -- in your [requirements.txt](https://github.com/akashmalla07/spring/blob/master/requirements.txt) you have this:

```
Django==1.8.3
django-nose==1.4.1
nose==1.3.7
requests==2.7.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

The tutorial you are following only has instructions on how to install the modules that their demo application requires, which is just Django.  So you need to install your extra modules too.

To do this, in the Bash console where you installed django, you need to run this command:

```
pip install -r /home/yourpythonanywhereusername/spring/requirements.txt
```

Don't forget to replace `yourpythonanywhereusername` with your actual PythonAnywhere username.

Comment: giles  after following your solution i got error that i have mentioned in my edited post please refer that and please help me.

Comment: @Gilesi was getting error while installing wsgiref==0.1.2 and i mentioned my error in question(edited) and i searched and used  pip install --upgrade setuptools  but it didnot worked for me

Comment: It looks like your web app is dependent on using Python 2.7 instead of Python 3; the instructions you're following are for a Python 3 website.  You need to delete the web app from the "Web" tab, then create a new one selecting the Python 2.7 option.  You'll also need to delete your virtualenv and create a new one using Python 2.7.

Comment: [These help pages](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/#ive-got-an-existing-web-app-that-im-trying-to-deploy) are probably a better guide for setting up your app than the Django Girls tutorial.  The tutorial is one of the best guides there is to creating your first Django website, but it's not a generic "how to deploy a Django application" guide -- it's very specific to the website they teach you how to build in the other sections of the tutorial.